(node:3588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??=' on execute "npm run dev" React - Vite
Recently I create a react project using Vite (this happen with every project I try to create), when I create it from command prompt works fine, however on VS Code, on execute
npm run dev

appear this message:

(node:3588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:149:18)
(Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)
(node:3588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.

This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().
To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag --unhandled-rejections=strict (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

(node:3588) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Currently, I'm using node version v20.12.2, I have reinstalled it, reinstall node module, and searching token "??=" in the files project, I foundnd a solution using
npm install -g pnpm

and use pnpm, but I have to change the node version every time I open the project, because VS code load with version 14.12 (I don't know if this bug is due to the same node problem or directly a VS code problem)
I would like to know how to fix the node problem with npm and make VS code use the node version I have installed.

What OS are you on? And how did you install node? If VS-Code uses a different node version than the command prompt, this seems to be an issue with your environment, especially your PATH. Do which node and which npm in both, your command prompt and VS-Code integrated shell. They probably will point to different locations ...

I´m using Windows 11, I tried using nvm and install it directly nodejs.org I don't know if there's a extra-step I have to do, How can I make them point to the same location?

Uninstall one of them

I keep getting the error and I have to change the node version every time I open the project.

if you are facing any problems while running the project, check your node version and if it is 20.6.0 I would recommend you upgrade it to the latest version then it will work just fine.
NVM
Use the following commands to install NVM, then install the latest version of Node.js using NVM:

sudo apt update to update the package repository

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.35.1/install.sh | bash to download and install NVM

restart the terminal

nvm –version to check the NVM version

nvm ls-remote to check available NVM releases

nvm install <version> install the latest version like this
nvm install 22.0.0

nvm use <version> To switch to the installed version, use: nvm use 22.0.0

Reinstalling Dependencies:
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install

Run your project
npm run dev


Thanks, I hope this solution works for you.
